# Ionic datetime only gives back initialized values

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic-framework, form-control

I am currently working on the development of an Ionic-Angular-app. For this I need a `datetime` component on a page, which should adjust the creation date of an object. For this I use `formGroup`, but when I select another date I always get the date initialized in the form.

Code from ts.file

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
    if (!paramMap.has('axleCounterId')) {
      return;
    }
    const axleCounterId = paramMap.get('axleCounterId');
    this.loadedAxleCounter = this.homeService.getAxleCounter(axleCounterId);
  });

  this.form = new FormGroup({
    date: new FormControl(this.loadedAxleCounter.creationDate, {
      updateOn: 'blur'
    }),
    dateTest: new FormControl(null, {
      updateOn: 'change'
    })
  })
}
```

Code from html:

```
<form [formGroup]='form'>
  <ion-item lines=none>
    <ion-avatar slot=start>
      <ion-icon *ngIf=loadedAxleCounter.creationDate name=checkmark-circle color=success size=large></ion-icon>
    </ion-avatar>
    <ion-label>
      <div style="white-space: normal; ">
        <h2>Date</h2>
        <h3>
          <ion-datetime id=datePickerPadding [pickerOptions]=customOption formControlName=date></ion-datetime>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</form>
```

does anyone see at first glance where my mistake is, or can anyone help me? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you create stackblitz with reproducible issue?

Comment: You can check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/iondatetime-min-max-ab8c1p?file=src/app/tab1/tab1.page.html and update with your code ;)

Comment: i updated tab2 with my code [link](https://iondatetime-min-max-upilgy.stackblitz.io/tabs/tab2) as you can see the event in the console.log only shows the "creationDateGiven" even when you update the date

Comment: Can you paste the editor url of the link/stackblitz you created?

Comment: I hope this one is the correct one now: https://stackblitz.com/edit/iondatetime-min-max-upilgy?file=src/app/tab2/tab2.page.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ion-datetime component internally updating the value property to the changed value in it's own handler method. You can check at [ion-datetime](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/e82ac39af919716dd00d3ecc00bd3e430cd6eaf7/core/src/components/datetime/datetime.tsx#L334)

But here we are using custom click handlers. So from our side manually need to patch form value. `Done` handler will give an `event` object on click. Which contains `Day, Month, Year`. So you can do something like below.

```
handler: (event) => {
  this.form.get('date').patchValue(new Date(event.day.text + "-" + event.month.text + "-" + event.year.text).toDateString());
  console.log(this.form.value);
}
```

### Forked and working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/iondatetime-min-max-k4usgu?file=src/app/tab2/tab2.page.ts)

Comment: i tried, but i have no reputations yet so i doesnt count, im sorry